# Python - Thousands separator that also works for decimals, keeping 4 significant digits

Tags: python, python-3.x, number-formatting

I'm using an API to get data about cryptocurrencies (https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?convert=USD) and as some of you may know, cryptocurrencies can be worth over $4000 (BTC) or less than $0.000001 for some other. I have to work and easily compare all those numbers.

In Canada, we use the **space** character as the thousands' separator. I want it to work for thousands but also to group the decimal digits. Also, I need a way to only keep a number of *significant* digits. For Bitcoin for example, I don't want the decimal part. I'd like to always have at least **4** significant digits, which basically means, if the `number >= 1000`, I don't need the decimal part (but I keep the full integer part), and if it's `< 0`, I want at least 3 additional digits after the first non-zero digit (with rounding if necessary).

Exemples of inputs => outputs I'd like:

```
65410845186.1      => 65 410 845 186
43245.1            => 43 245
285.1234           => 285.1
0.01234567         => 0.123 5
0.001234054        => 0.001 234
0.001034538        => 0.001 035
0.00010001         => 0.000 100 0
1                  => 1.000
1.0006             => 1.001
```

The script needs to work on different operating systems. I don't think any `locale` or trivial `format` implementation could work here. What would be the best approach to add the space separator both ways, using a dot as the decimal separator, while keeping 4 significant digits (with rounding if necessary) except for numbers `>= 1000` where I just keep the integer part?

I got the space separator to work as a thousands' separator from another piece of code I found here on StackOverflow:

```py
def splitThousands(s, tSep=' ', dSep=','):
    if s.rfind('.')>0:
        rhs=s[s.rfind('.')+1:]
        s=s[:s.rfind('.')]
        if len(s) <= 3: return s + dSep + rhs
        return splitThousands(s[:-3], tSep) + tSep + s[-3:] + dSep + rhs
    else:
        if len(s) <= 3: return s
        return splitThousands(s[:-3], tSep) + tSep + s[-3:]
```

It doesn't take into account the number of significant digits however and doesn't add the separator for the decimal part.

Note: Those values fluctuate **a lot**, I do **not** really mind extremely corner case scenarios where a float value of `1.0004999999999` would be rounded to `1.001`.

Comment: Express the value in million units?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque What does that mean exactly?

Comment: 0.0001234 * 1,000,000 = 123.40 - which is easier to the eye to comprehend and compare

Comment: What is `type(value)`... are you dealing with integers, floats or decimals for instance?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's easier since you don't have a really obvious order of magnitude compared to $0.01. Considering I can be comparing 0.001234, 0.0001234, 0.00001234, I'd like to keep it as is with the separators to make it obvious to compare to $1 or $0.01.

Comment: @JonClements Strings. It can be converted to whatever it needs to, that doesn't really matter as long as I can output it as a string at the end. Currently I'm converting the string to a float and then back to a string.

Comment: Okay - trying to understand if it's the management of the value or the input/output of the value you're trying to get going. Could you provide matching input/outputs for an example please?

Comment: @JonClements I added a trivial example. I want the output to be `1 234 567` in that case which isn't complicated, the complicated part is the separator for smaller numbers and keeping the appropriate number of significant digits for the decimal part.

Comment: And for 0. for that?

Comment: FWIW, you may want to consider `decimal` i/o `float` types for the range of values you are manipulating, and the importance of precision

Comment: Maybe the [`locale`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html) module (and [`locale.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.format) function) may help? Or a specialized package like [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/numbers.html).

Comment: @jdehesa I didn't find any format in the `locale.format` to add a separator to decimal numbers or to keep X significant digits. Maybe I'm not looking at the right place, if it exists, I'd definitely be interested in using it.

Comment: @dnLL A locale defines all of those options (see [`localeconv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.localeconv)); however, it does not seem to be possible to customize them from code, looks like you would have to rely on the locales installed on the system...

Comment: @jdehesa Considering this is for a public Discord bot project, I can't ask everyone to edit their locales on their systems, so I need something that will work with a variety of systems (Windows and UNIX) without too much of a hassle for anyone who's running the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly a clean or straightforward solution, but here is a function that fits the bill:

```
from math import floor, log10

def format_btc(value, tSep=' ', dSep='.', precision=4, grouping=3):
    int_digits = max(int(floor(log10(value))) + 1, 0)
    if int_digits >= precision:
        int_part = int(round(value))
        decimal_part = None
    else:
        int_part = int(floor(value))
        decimal_part = value % 1.0
    int_str = str(int_part)[::-1]
    int_str = [int_str[i:i + grouping][::-1]
               for i in range(0, len(int_str), grouping)]
    int_str = tSep.join(reversed(int_str))
    if decimal_part is None:
        return int_str
    if int_digits > 0:
        num_decimals = precision - int_digits
    else:
        decimal_str = "{:.{precision}e}".format(decimal_part, precision=precision - 1)
        decimal_pos = -int(decimal_str.split("e")[1])
        num_decimals = decimal_pos + precision - 1
    decimal_str = "{:.{precision}f}".format(decimal_part, precision=num_decimals)
    decimal_str = decimal_str.split(".")[1]
    if int_digits > 0:
        decimal_str = decimal_str[:precision - int_digits]
    decimal_str = [decimal_str[i:i + grouping] for i in range(0, len(decimal_str), grouping)]
    decimal_str = tSep.join(decimal_str)
    return dSep.join((int_str, decimal_str))

tests = [65410845186.123456, 4324.1, 285.1234, 0.01234567, 0.001234054,
         0.001034538, 0.00010001, 1390390000.0, 1.0006]

for test in tests:
    print("{:<20f} => {:s}".format(test, format_btc(test)))
```

Output:

```
65410845186.123459   => 65 410 845 186
4324.100000          => 4 324
285.123400           => 285.1
0.012346             => 0.012 35
0.001234             => 0.001 234
0.001035             => 0.001 035
0.000100             => 0.000 100 0
1390390000.000000    => 1 390 390 000
1.000600             => 1.001
```

Comment: Some of the inputs don't seem to work, for example `1390390000.0` returns  `1 390 390 0` instead of `1 390 390 000` (`463196000.0` is also problematic). If it wasn't for that, I definitely don't mind using a custom function like that (which means there is no easy elegant solution). I will dig deeper into your code once I'm back home but I think it could work.

Comment: @dnLL Whops, you're right... I've changed the code, seems to work for that case now...

Comment: Sure seems to be working with all the numbers I'm crunching in the API (https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?convert=USD) right now. I will do deeper testings later.

Comment: I see you made another edit, the results seem to be the same however (which are correct), care to explain the difference? You basically added `int` casts and a `decimal_nums` and `decimal_exp` vars.

Comment: @dnLL Yes, as you said it's the same, I just changed how to extract the decimal part string. Instead of using hardcoded string indices (which should be safe because of the string format and the logic, but seems dirtier) I changed it to split the exponential notation string at `e` and `.`. Still not terribly clean or anything, but I feel more comfortable with it...

Comment: It seems to be covering all corner case scenarios, really, I tested integers like `1` and it returns `1.000` which is perfectly valid. It basically works with any positive value. I will mark this as the accepted answer unless someone comes up with some miraculous one line solution.

Comment: @dnLL Glad to know, thanks. I'd be also interested to know about such miracle answer :D

Comment: Rounding sometimes doesn't work, something like 1.0006 returns 1.000 rather than 1.001. I didn't specify initially, I will edit my original question and examples. As a workaround, using a precision of `precision+1` and then rounding at `precision` would work.

Comment: @dnLL Aw yes you're right. Rounding is working in #4, but in that example is kind of a corner case... I'll take a look

Comment: Interestingly it works for `0.23456` but not for `1.23456`. It's basically only a problem for values > 1 and < 1000 (or 10000 if precision is 5 and so on, `999.49` for example).

Comment: @dnLL Okay new update... This is quite ugly, but now I just format the decimal part once to find the necessary precision and then again to actually get the fixed-point format... Give it some testing and see.